# Finding $\sum_{k=1}^n k \text{ } 2^k$

Tags: summation

I need to calculate this sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \text{ } 2^k$$
I tried to meddle with double sums using $$\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n k\right )\left( \sum_{j=1}^n 2^j \right)$$ but It doesn't seem to be the most fitting approach.

Comment: See e.g. the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Compute $\;\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k x^k=x\sum_{k=1}^n k x^{k-1}=x\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n x^k\biggr)'$ instead, then substitute $2$ for $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was able to continue from there.

Comment: Glad to have been helpful!